# Update dependent entries in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with a SQL Server CE for a private project and I'm trying to update related records.

Two of my tables are:

Document 1-n DocumentFile

Documment:
- Id (1)

DocumentFile
- DocumentId (n)
- Name

Now my question:
I want to update the complete dependent List (DocumentFile) of one document-entry.
f.e. 
- a document (id 20) has 5 dependent entries in the DocumentFile-Table.
- the user removes 3 of the files and adds 1 more.

The result should be: 3 dependent entries (5-3+1) in the DocumentFile-table.

I tried to just remove the Collection and add the new entries, but EF will not delete the old ones automatically. It just adds the new list to the table.

Do i really need to delete every single dependent documentfile-entry and add the new collection?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the user has deleted 3 files, presumably you have code which accesses each entity and calls *DeleteObject* resulting in 3 entities in the Deleted state. The user will add one more file and so an additional entity will be created using *AddObject* and so the context will contain another entry in the Added state. You will also have 2 entities in the Unchanged state. When you call *SaveChanges* on the context the appropriate SQL will get generated and EF will manage your update. If you are following these steps you should not need to delete every single dependent entity.